# Access the column field name from the columns.filterable.cell.template function in Kendo

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-autocomplete

Because I'm using a lot of kendo grids spread in the whole web app, I start to introduce some redundant code that causes me a lot of troubles. Imagine to have something like:

```
//MVC:
...
columns.Bound(c => c.Column1).Filterable(f => f.Extra(false)
.Operators(o => o.ForString(str => str.Clear().Contains("Contains")))
.Cell(c => .ShowOperators(false).Template("column1Filter")))
.Title("Column One"); 
...

//JS:
function column1Filter(container) {
    container.element.kendoAutoComplete({
        filter: "contains",
        dataTextField: "Column1",
        dataValueField: "Column1",
        valuePrimitive: true,
        dataSource: container.dataSource
    });
}
```

Then, having this method reproduced for each single columns in each single grids. Is there any way where I can I have only one method that creates the kendo autocomplete? E.G:

```
function genericAutocompleteFilter(container) {
    var columnsName = //...Meh!
    container.element.kendoAutoComplete({
        filter: "contains",
        dataTextField: columnsName,
        dataValueField: columnsName,
        valuePrimitive: true,
        dataSource: container.dataSource
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a closure to get the function you need customized for you columnName. something like:

```
function getAutoCompleteFunction(columnName) {

    return function (container) {
                    container.element.kendoAutoComplete({
                        filter: "contains",
                        autoBind: false,
                        dataTextField: columnName,
                        dataValueField: columnName,
                        valuePrimitive: true,
                        dataSource: container.dataSource
                    })
}
```

and then use getAutoCompleteFunction("column1") for example.

Comment: Thanks for your help. however, I need something that I can user when a I call this function from razor

Answer (score 0):

At the end, there are two ways to do it. For the column "color", we can use it with kendo MVC (razor). While the column "size", it's from @massimo-franciosa 's suggestion.

http://dojo.telerik.com/uqita/5.